# how to display a predetermined value in the date field?

Tags: php

I like to show  predetermined value in the date field from database.

```
<?php
    @$row=$cond->first_row();
?>

<input type="date" name="dob" value="<?php echo @$row->dob;?> ">
```

@$row->dob contains the date fetched from database(My SQL).It is stored as DATE. The displayed date should be in editable form.

This code is not showing the value . I am a starter in php!.. Please help...

Comment: What does $row->dob contain. And why are you suppressing all error messages using @?

Comment: what does $row->dob contain ? the format ? the data type ?.. please give some more information

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
date( "Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime( $row->dob ) );
```

for more detail visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
 date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($row->dob))
```